# Blank purple screen on boot, can only boot from specific sequence

Tags: 16.04, drivers, intel-graphics

Heres a crazy one, please go easy I am super new to linux. I am still going through the solutions on this forum but so far no luck.

When I boot Ubuntu normally I get a blank purple screen and no response, no ability to switch off the GUI. I have to force reboot (hold down the power button). When I do get it to boot (using the below) if I close the lid or hit "suspend" it does not respond to any attempt to wake it up and I force reboot agin.

As mentioned, there is one sequence in recovery mode that works --

Recovery>dpkg fix>failsafeX>continue to normal boot

There is a ton of feedback on each step, I will get it when I can tomorrow. In the meantime, I am reading alot about graphics cards, what can I install to check my drivers?

I have the following fron lspci

```
vince@BahamutZero:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
vince@BahamutZero:~$
```

update 1 - seeing this in my error logs
[Error messages in log about com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800864/error-messages-in-log-about-com-canonical-unity-scope-home)

is it related? what can I dig into? im going to force reinstall unity to see whats up.

edit 3
No luck there. what can I upload or add to help? a boot-repair log or something similar?

Comment: ended up reinstalling the entire OS :(  ... anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt look like I was able to fix this. For anyone who is just starting to have this issue, use alt f5 or a similar combo to get to a terminal and shutdown using the -h flag!! much less likely to cause damage then the hard reboots I was doing.

http://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-shutdown-reboot-restart-system/